# TexMaker does not launch

Tags: texmaker

I have been using the editor TexMaker for a while now and all of the sudden it just stopped working/launching. I am using windows 10 enterprise. It is hard to describe because when I double click on the texmaker icon or after choosing a file and open with TexMaker, I see texmaker.exe appearing on the task manager and the bottom task bar but nothing else is happening. I tried to deinstall and re-install it several times, but no success. When I use a different editor, e.g. texworks, the file compiles normally. So I gather that there is nothing wrong with miktex 2.9.

Sorry, for that ambiguous error description. Any ideas? Unfortunately, google couldn't help this time. I would not like to change editors to be honest.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is an old thread, but I was having a similar problem and didn't need to re-install, deleting xm1 solved it by itself (though it looks like all my settings are gone).

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. I needed to delete the xm1 folder in the AppData as well, then re-install texmaker.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get to the root. At least in my case, the "Geometries"-settings in the `texmaker.ini` file caused the problem. I copied the old `texmaker.ini` file to save the settings and then deleted the one in the /AppData/Roaming/xm1 folder, start texmaker to generate the default `texmaker.ini` file and than copied the default Geometries settings to the original file. That way you can keep your settings :)
and there was no need for reinstalling texmaker.

Or just simply copy the beneath:

```
Geometries\MainwindowWidth=1770
Geometries\MainwindowHeight=980
Geometries\MainwindowX=30
Geometries\MainwindowY=30
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a portable install that did not require root privileges. After deleting the `texmaker.ini` and `texmakerapp.ini` files inside of the root of the portable install folder I fixed my issue.